# DIN 41612 current rating - peak or RMS?

Tags: current, connector, rms

DIN 41612 connectors are rated at 2A per pin.  Is this the absolute maximum current or RMS?  I want to use a DIN connector for power level audio.  Music signal peaks commonly reach 24 dB (16x) above the RMS level.  If the current rating is RMS, what is a safe peak maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Like all ampacity ratings, this is based on the acceptable level of conductor -- or pin/socket for a connector, heating, and is thus a RMS rating.